# Show the total rating in WooCommerce for current user id

Tags: php, sql, woocommerce, product, rating

I am using the code from: [Display total customers reviews and ratings average in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613317/display-total-customers-reviews-and-ratings-average-in-woocommerce/50614786#50614786)

From this functions how can I get a total product rating for each current user id?

Like in `get_total_reviews_count()` function below which get from current user id.

```
function get_total_reviews_count(){
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

return get_comments(array(
'status' => 'approve',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_type' => 'product',
'post_author' => $user_id,
'count' => true
));
}
```

Product rating function :

```
function get_products_ratings(){
global $wpdb;

return $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT t.slug, tt.count
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t
JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE t.slug LIKE 'rated-%' AND tt.taxonomy LIKE 'product_visibility'
ORDER BY t.slug
");
}

function products_rating_average_html(){
$stars = 1;
$average = 0;
$total_count = 0;
foreach( get_products_ratings() as $values ){
$average += $stars * $values->count;
$total_count += $values->count;
$stars++;
}
return '<p class="rating-average">'.round($average / $total_count, 1).' / 5 '. __('Stars average').'</p>';
}
```

Comment: You should always mention the linked original source code that you are using in your question, when it comes from StackOverFlow.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Sorry I'm still new in stack overflow and thank for your advice, it's from your previous post sir hehe2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613317/display-total-customers-reviews-and-ratings-average-in-woocommerce Can you please help me solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: What means "show total rating" for the current user for you? How do you see that? Is it an average rating on all ratings for the current customer?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Exactly, so for who register as a seller, each seller I will show the average overall rating their product in their menu. Example in get_total_reviews_count() function,     'post_author' => $user_id,

Comment: That is completely different as sellers are not the authors of the comments in their products. So this is getting complicated and you should update your question, with those details. Your question is not clear actually.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec

   Sorry because can't explain properly, like the function get_total_reviews_count (), its already work perfectly like I want  which show how much total review each user id. Example id A=20 total review and id B=15 total reviews.

    So for the Product rating function, I just want it to work same like get_total_reviews_count () function, can it be done? Example id A=4/5 average overall rating and id B=3/5  average overall rating

Comment: function products_rating_average_html() only works with a SQL query and not with get_total_reviews_count()…