# Avoid a NAN result error when displaying ratings average in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have this code in a plugin (custom dashboard widget plugin) and the output displays in a Dashboard widget. If someone submits a product review, the error goes away. But I would like know how to make the error go away when there are no product reviews.

I am using the code from: 
[Display total customers reviews and ratings average in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613317/display-total-customers-reviews-and-ratings-average-in-woocommerce/50614786#50614786)

The error is:
Warning: Division by zero
and it refers to this line:

```
return '<p class="rating-average"><b>'.round($average / $total_count, 1).' / 5 </b>'. __('Rating Stars Average').'</p>';
```

The output displays as: NAN / 5 Rating Stars Average
Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Please, next time when you are using the code from a stackOverFlow answer, first always add the link in your question and If you have not made any changes to this code don't add the code in your question, just keep the link. In this particular case, you can add a comment in this existing answer warning that there is a problem first, before asking a question.

Comment: Yes, I always try to find the original question where I got from if I got if from here, but that is not always so easy. Is there an easy way except for bookmarking it for later reference?

Comment: You can make a search on the function name [`products_rating_average_html()`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=products_rating_average_html) for example and many other ways to find something and you will find it easily.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try harder next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `if` and check to see if `$total_count === 0`:

```
function products_rating_average_html(){
    $stars = 1;
    $average = 0;
    $total_count = 0;
    foreach( get_products_ratings() as $values ){
        $average += $stars * $values->count;
        $total_count += $values->count;
        $stars++;
    }

    if ($total_count === 0) {
        return 'No Reviews';
    }

    return '<p class="rating-average"><b>'.round($average / $total_count, 1).' / 5 </b>'. __('Rating Stars Average').'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ben, I should have thought of that :)