# How to get average rating and reviews for custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rating

I found and use the code (Thanks to the creator of this code!) [Display total customers reviews and ratings average in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613317/display-total-customers-reviews-and-ratings-average-in-woocommerce/50614786#50614786)

It displays (in my case) on the product page and on the taxonomy page the number of all reviews and rating from the entire store.

For example:
I have a custom taxonomy "brand_name".
I want Adidas products (taxonomy "brand_name") to display only their average rating of all products and quantity. And only if the overall rating of the goods is more than 3 stars.
and for Nike (taxonomy "brand_name"), only their average rating of all products and quantity were displayed. And only if the overall rating of the goods is more than 3 stars.

Thank you very much for your help and attention to my post.

**The code I use (original above link)**

```
function get_total_reviews_count(){
    return get_comments(array(
        'status'   => 'approve',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        'count' => true
    ));
}

function get_products_ratings(){
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT t.slug, tt.count
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
        WHERE t.slug LIKE 'rated-%' AND tt.taxonomy LIKE 'product_visibility'
        ORDER BY t.slug
    ");
}

function products_count_by_rating_html(){
    $star = 1;
    $html = '';
    foreach( get_products_ratings() as $values ){
        $star_text = '<strong>'.$star.' '._n('Star', 'Stars', $star, 'woocommerce').'<strong>: ';
        $html .= '<li class="'.$values->slug.'">'.$star_text.$values->count.'</li>';
        $star++;
    }
    return '<ul class="products-rating">'.$html.'</ul>';
}

function products_rating_average_html(){
    $stars = 1;
    $average = 0;
    $total_count = 0;
    if( sizeof(get_products_ratings()) > 0 ) :
        foreach( get_products_ratings() as $values ){
            $average += $stars * $values->count;
            $total_count += $values->count;
            $stars++;
        }
        return '<p class="rating-average">'.round($average / $total_count, 1).' / 5 '. __('Stars average').'</p>';
    else :
        return '<p class="rating-average">'. __('No reviews yet', 'woocommerce').'</p>';
    endif;
}
```

```
echo '<p>'.__('Total reviews','woocommerce').': '.get_total_reviews_count().'</p>';
    echo products_count_by_rating_html();
    echo products_rating_average_html();
```